# How to get Data From Vaadin to HTML/Jsp File?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, vaadin7, vaadin6

I have created a HTML page that is called from Vaadin.

I have written the following code to call HTML page from Vaadin.

```
ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource("VAADIN/map.jsp");
Embedded browser= new Embedded("",resource);
browser.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
browser.setSizeFull();     

browser.setData("Test Data");
```

This code successfully redirect to `map.jsp` file, but i am unable to send the data with it.. I have added `browser.setData("Test Data");`, but i am unable to understand how to get this data in `jsp` file.

Kindly guide me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the data as url parameters:

```
VAADIN/map.jsp?param1=Value1&param2=value2
```

Comment: did this help you, if so please check it as answer or vote up!

Answer (score 1):

With Vaadin 7 you can do something like this:

```
ExternalResource jsp = new ExternalResource("page.jsp?param=ok");
BrowserFrame frame = new BrowserFrame("JSP:", jsp);
layout.addComponent(frame);
```

You can test it with the following `page.jsp` file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        param = <%= request.getParameter("param") %>
    </body>
</html>
```